# Can't install uploaded APK from my own server

Tags: android, server, apk

I want to upload my app (.apk) file on my own server, and download it by calling the url from  my mobile browser.

I've done the following:

1- I've correctly set the following mime type on server: 
application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk;

2- I've tried unsigned and signed (with release and debug keys)

3- I've checked the "unknown source" option from my mobile

But the following happens:

1- The app is successfully downloaded

2- When I ask to install the downloaded file, the permissions window appears, so I can click next
3- When I click next, it says "installing" for few seconds, after that it says "app not installed"

What can I do to solve this problem?

Notes:

a. If I download the apk from e-mail for example, its installed successfully

b. I've tried with many mobiles, older versions of android successfully install the app, but  only newer versions have the problem mentioned above

It works on Sony Arc S, Android 4.0.4

It does't work on Sony xperia Z1, Android 5.0.2

Update: When I use (Android) Firefox browser instead of chrome the app is installed successfully!

Comment: Does your app use "display system wide alerts"?

Comment: Use the LogCat to log what problem is happening and post on the question, most likely the APK is not correctly build, or its a permission issue. Also, please post the Device and the Build number

Comment: I edited my question, I downloaded apk form server then tried  to install it, But I can't install it successfully

Comment: 'and download it by calling the url'. The url? What is the url? If you place the file on your server and the url is 'http://myserver.com/myapps/myapp.apk' then you are done and any browser can download it. No need to fiddle around with mime types.